# Program that understands pasted math from a pdf

Tags: pdf

I paste the math from a pdf into Microsoft Word and clearly Microsoft Word can't understand pasted math from a pdf:

[image: example]

Is there a program that can keep the original pdf formatting including the math? Not necessarily a pdf editor

Comment: I know from OpenOffice/LibreOffice that there's a formula editor. Something similar also seems to exist in word. Useful reading: [4 Ways to Insert Equations in Microsoft Word](http://www.wikihow.com/Insert-Equations-in-Microsoft-Word), [How to Convert PDF containing Math (made from LaTeX) to Word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116229/how-to-convert-pdf-containing-math-made-from-latex-to-word), [Automatic Equation Converion from PDF - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qC1hwJ8KFL8). There also seems to be a tool named Able2Dic capable of converting the entire PDF to DOC.

Comment: Why is getting the math formula into MS Word important for you? Why not leave it in the PDF? What is your overall objective?

Comment: @Ryan MSWord is not that important, I'm just curious if there is a way to edit and typeset math given just a PDF rather than recreate the entire math with LaTex or something. So the objective is just to be able to quickly modify / use of expressions of math in a pdf. I gather from your questions that this is not possible.